# Ember.js - Error while processing route if URL hit directly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I keep getting the following error from the route handler for a single object (user).  If I click the link to view/show a single object (user) it works fine, but when I refresh the page at this route's url I keep getting this error.

URL that causes the error when visiting directly:

```
/users/:user_id
```

Error message in console:

```
Error while processing route: users.show Assertion Failed: Expected an
object as `data` in a call to `push`/`update` for ember-app@model:user:,
but was undefined Error: Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` 
in a call to `push`/`update` for ember-app@model:user: , but was undefined
```

app/router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('users', function() {
        this.route('show', { path: '/:user_id' });
    });
});
```

app/routes/users/show.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        console.log('show route model hook'); //Hook firing on refresh
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

I am using Ember 1.8.1 and Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.12.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your 'user' Model, Serializer and the `GET /users` response from the server?

Comment: Even better if you can make it work in jsbin for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server probably does not return proper JSON for `/users/:id`.

If you are using `RESTAdapter`, JSON returned from server should be something like

```
user: {
  id: 1,
  other_attrs: '...'
}
```

When entering `ShowRoute` from list of users, all users were already loaded using `store.find('user')` method (i.e. loading via `/users` server request), thus `return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);` does not make request to the server at all, it only returns already loaded user. Thus there is no error.

Comment: Also consider upgrading to `Ember.Data` 1.0.0-beta.14.1 - error messages for this kind of issues are much more _user friendly_.

Comment: You were right.  I did not have the respond_to block setup appropriately for users/show.  Thank you!